# The method valueOf(Class<T>, String) in the type Enum is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Enum<T>>, String)

Tags: java, class, generics, enums

I dont know what am I doing wrong... In constructor, I wanna receive a Class of an enum, and I want to return the correct enum, when a value passed as parameter to convert().

```
public final class EnumSimplesConverter<T extends Enum<T>> {
    private final Class<Enum<T>> enumClass;

    public EnumSimplesConverter(Class<Enum<T>> enumClass) {
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    public Enum<T> convert(String value) throws TypeConverterException {
        return Enum.valueOf(this.enumClass, value);
    }
}
```

But its gives me the error on "valuesOf()":
"The method valueOf(Class, String) in the type Enum is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Enum>, String)"

Comment: `private final Class<T> enumClass;`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the type and the constructor:

```
private final Class<T> enumClass;

public EnumSimplesConverter(Class<T> enumClass) {
    this.enumClass = enumClass;
}
```

you already enforce the `T` via `T extends Enum<T>`